# toggle_paused() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' when view runs models method

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am getting the error TypeError: toggle_paused() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' when I trigger ToggleView(). I am still pretty new to Django and im not sure how to resolve the issue. I tried using @classmethod on the method but that just moved the error to another method. Any help would be much appreciated!

```html
class Entry(models.Model):

    @property
    def is_paused(self):
        """
        Determine whether or not this entry is paused
        """
        return bool(self.pause_time)
        
    def pause(self):
        pass

    def unpause(self, date=None):
      pass  
    
    def toggle_paused(self):
        if self.is_paused:
            self.unpause()
        else:
            self.pause()


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.hours = Decimal('%.5f' % round(self.total_hours, 5))
        super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```html
def ToggleView(request):

    Entry.toggle_paused()
    Entry.save()
```

Comment: You are calling the method from the class `Entry` you need an instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Entry is a class, you need to create an instance from it and pass it as a parameter to your function.

Something like:

```
entry = Entry()

def toogle_view(request, entry):
    entry.toogle_paused()
    entry.save()
```